# correct file permissions for trac and git user to access gitolite server repos

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, git, file-permissions, trac

In my server I host some git repositories via gitolite, and have a trac for every repository.

I have a user called git to push/pull from server (`git clone git@server:repo`). and trac is a apache vhost with mod_wsgi. this runs with the www-data user.

So what riddles me (maybe because I have not much of a clue about file-permissions at all) is what's the best permissions setup (chown, chmod) for the git repositories (`/home/git/repositories/`...).

www-data (or trac) needs to at least read permissions (i think). and git (or gitolite) needs obviously read/write permissions to push changesets.

I tried a little bit around (i.e. adding www-data and/or git to the www-data/git group), but didn't got it right. at least one of the two don't work (git or trac).

any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The most secure way of doing it I would say is to have a group called git-readers

add git and www-data to it, then have the following folder structure:

```
/home/git - git:git-readers u=rwx,g=rx,o=
/home/git/repositories - git:git u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

This will allow www-data into the folder for reading, but only give the git user write access. Any other user can't do anything.

If you want to add additional writers, I would add another group git-writers and add the users and git to it as well as the git-readers group, then use the following structure:

```
/home/git - git:git-readers u=rwx,g=rx,o=
/home/git/repositories - git:git-writers u=rwx,g=rwxs,o=rx
```

Note the 's' in the group permissions. This makes the writer users use git-writers group as their default group. This will only work properly if the writers are all umask 0002.

Comment: perfect thx. fyi: for some reason you need to restart apache after changing the permissions (and creating the git-readers group). seems like this was the problem in the first place, but not sure.

Comment: Yes, only new processes gain newly added groups. Restarting apache is needed to do that.

Comment: this isn't working. newly created files in the repos have the wrong permissions. could you show me the chmod/own commands precisely.

Answer (score 0):

in case of gitolite [push commits to git (gitolite) repository messes up file permissions (no more trac access)](https://serverfault.com/questions/221978/push-commits-to-git-gitolite-repository-messes-up-file-permissions-no-more-tra/222015#222015)